# Show $\vDash \phi \to \psi \Leftrightarrow \{\phi\} \vDash \psi$.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Dirk van Dalen. "*Logic and Structure (Universitext)*" (p. 29)

> **Definition 1.2.1** A mapping $v : PROP \to \{0, 1\}$ is a valuation if
> $
> v(\phi \land \psi) = min(v(\phi), v(\psi)),\\
> v(\phi \lor \psi) = max(v(\phi), v(\psi)),\\
> v(\phi \to\psi)=0 \leftrightarrow v(\phi)=1 \text{and} v(\psi)=0,\\
> v(\phi \leftrightarrow \psi)=1 \leftrightarrow v(\phi)=v(\psi), v(\lnot\phi) = 1 − v(\phi)\\
> v(\bot) = 0\\
> $

> **Definition 1.2.4**
> (i) $\phi$  is a tautology if $ [[\phi]]v$ = 1 for all valuations $v$,
> (ii) $\vDash \phi$  stands for ‘$\phi$ is a tautology’,
> (iii) Let $\Gamma$  be a set of propositions, then $\gamma \vDash \phi$  iff for all $v$ : $([[\phi]] v = 1 \text{for all } \psi \in \Gamma) \to [[\phi]]v = 1$.

My proof skeleton of one side of the proof: $\{\phi\} \vDash \psi \Rightarrow \, \vDash \phi \to \psi$.

Since $\{\phi\} \vDash \psi$, I know that for all valuations $v$, $[[\phi]]_v = 1 \Rightarrow [[\psi]]_v = 1$.
Proof:

- I start assuming $[[\phi]]_v = 1$

  - $[[\phi]]_v = 1 \to [[\psi]]_v = 1$
  - $[[\psi]]_v = 1$
- $[[\phi]]_v = 1 \to [[\psi]]_v = 1$
- $\vdots$

Am I on the right track ?

Comment: You should not use the symbol $\rightarrow$ as both a logical symbol in well-formed formulas *and* as a meta-logical simple for "implies" in statements of propositions. For example, $\{\phi\}\models\psi\rightarrow\models\phi\rightarrow\psi$ is both difficult to read and prone to parsing errors. In general, I suggest you rewrite your proof attempt using more words and sentences, and fewer symbols and bullets.

Comment: To add to halrankard's remark, if you like using abbreviations, you could use a double arrow $\Rightarrow$ for a meta-linguistic "if then".

Comment: After your edit, your implication in "If $[[\phi]]_v = 1$ then $[[\psi]]_v = 1$" should also be a $\Rightarrow$: It is an English statement, rather than a formula.

Comment: Thank you, @lemontree. Just going through your explanation. Missed to add $[[\psi]]_v = 1$ in my second bullet point.

Comment: I cannot find that line, @lemontree. You say it is an English statement. Could you tell me where are you looking at ?

Comment: I was being unclear -- it is supposed to be an "English" (~= meta language, as opposed to object language ("formula")) statement, but right now it is a mixture of object and meta language: Your "$[[\phi]]_v = 1 \to [[\psi]]_v = 1$" should be "$[[\phi]]_v = 1 \Rightarrow [[\psi]]_v = 1$". What is intended is an English "if ... then", and that can be abbreviated $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, @lemontree. I looked closely into the book, and I see there is a different kind of implication. However, I do not understand why it is supposed to be an English sentence and that symbol belongs to the meta-language. Could you explain, please ?

Comment: "$[[\phi]]_v = 1$" and "$[[\psi]]_v = 1$" are statements of the meta language (~= "mathematical English"): They are equations and thus mathematical facts. They use abbreviatory symbols ("$=$", "[[.]]"), but technically are expressions in ordinary language ("The truth value of $\phi$ under $v$ is $1$"). When asserting a conditional between two mathematical facts, such as "If $\phi$ is true under $v$ then $\psi$ is true under $v$", that will be a meta-linguistic,  informal "if ... then", abbreviated $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: On the other hand, the symbol $\to$ is a symbol of the inductively defined formal language of logic and can only connect formulas to form a new formula. Putting an object language implication $\to$ between two facts (such as truth value equations) does not make sense, because $\to$ only connects formulas, and $[[\phi]]_v = 1$ is not a formula. Hence why you probably mean $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: Oh, that's really interesting @lemontree ! To understand a little deeper...if I say "$n$ is even $\to$ $n^2$ is even", does it really should be $n$ is even $\Rightarrow$ $n^2$ is even ? This is the first time I wonder about this.

Comment: If you otherwise use $\to$ for formulas, then yes, it should be $\Rightarrow$ in that example. But the notation is not standardized; often you find $\Rightarrow$ for what is $\to$ in van Dalen and vice versa, or some completely other symbols (e.g. $\supset, \rightsquigarrow$). In many situations it is clear what is meant from context; but when writing out technical details about logic such as this proof, one should keep the two apart to avoid confusion.

Comment: I understand it clearly, now. Thank you so much, @lemontree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the assumption that $[[\phi]]_v = 1$ is correct.
The $[[\psi]]_v$ in your first sub-bullet point is strange; that's just an unknown number (a yet to be determined truth value) standing there, but after an "if ... then" one expects a statement. So just do without the sub bullet points and conclude $[[\psi]]_v = 1$ directly.
You should also generally add brief justifications how you obtain your results: Here, you used the assumption that $\phi \vDash \psi$.
Afterwards, you want to use this result to conclude that the implication $\phi \to \psi$ is true under the given valuation, justified by definition 1.2.1.

To complete the proof for the first direction, you then have to cover the other case: $[[\phi]]_v = 0$. That is, you do a proof by cases on the possible truth values of $\phi$, and obtain that the implication follows in eihter case.

Finally, you should make it clear what that $v$ is you are talking about: You are carrying out the proof for an arbitrary $v$, then conclude that since $v$ was arbitary, the above holds for all valuations, hence $\vDash$.

Taking this together, an improved version of your attempt looks as follows:

> Assume $\phi \vDash \psi$.
> Let $v$ be an arbitrary valuation.
> There are two cases to distinguish:
>
> 1. $[[\phi]]_v = 1$.
>    By the assumption $\phi \vDash \psi$, it follows that $[[\psi]]_v$ = 1.
>    Then by the truth table of implication, $[[\phi \to \psi]]_v = 1$.
> 2. $[[\phi]]_v = 0$.
>    $\vdots$
>
> In both cases it holds that $[[\phi \to \psi]]_v = 1$.
> Since $v$ was arbitrary, the above holds for all valuations, hence $\vDash \phi \to \psi$.

Comment: Thank you so much, @lemontree. Really appreciate your insight and deep explanations.

Comment: This is my attempt: 2. $[[\phi]]_v = 0$. By the truth table of implication, $[[\phi \to \phi]]_v = 1$. Is it correct ?

Comment: In $\vDash \phi \to \psi$, the set of hypothesis is empty. Does it play a role in these proofs ? As there is no valuation that makes the hypothesis false (because there are none), it means that $\phi \to \psi$ is a tautology ?

Comment: Yes to both of your comments.

Comment: That there are no premises in $\vDash$ plays a role in the proof in so far as the statement "$[[\phi \to \psi]]_v = 1$ "is not conditioned on the truth value of any premises (because, as you say, there aren't any), and yes, this means it is a tautology. Does this answer what you were after?

Comment: Really clear. Thank you so much, @lemontree.